# Consume large xml from hdfs with spark-streaming

Tags: xml, scala, hdfs, spark-streaming

I am `listening` to an `hdfs` directory for `xml` records with a `spark-streaming`- [`textFileStream()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/api/streaming/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.html). The problem is that my records are large (and one-liners); they can near 1G in size.

I do:

```
val xmlStream = ssc.textFileStream(monitoredDirectory).map { ("",_) }
```

But spark splits my file for processing to better parallelism. Xml being an un-splittable format, my processing on the file does not end well.

How can I tell spark not to split my file? Or are there other ways to handle large xml files?

Comment: Can you add the code you are currently using?

Comment: The code, as simple as it is.

Comment: what version of spark are you using? are you trying to simply read the files as whole text files? is there a reason to use spark streaming as opposed to structured streaming?

Comment: I am using spark 1.6, so no structured streaming.

Comment: have you already tried the [spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) library?

Comment: I tried and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/blob/master/README.md), like suggested *gtosto*, like so:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}
import com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlInputFormat

val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
conf.set(XmlInputFormat.START_TAG_KEY, "<xxx>")
conf.set(XmlInputFormat.END_TAG_KEY, "</xxx>")
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(conf)

val xml = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable,Text,XmlInputFormat](monitoredDirectory,true,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion to manage large files the streaming is not the best solution. The easy way is to manage them with a simply

```
sc.textfile("newfileinthefolder", partition=1)
```

and call this job with a listener in the folder, but in this way you loose (or delay) the real time computation features of your solution. Consider if you don't need a Near Real Time features.

Another solution, but I am not so confident about this, could be manage the batchDuration of the StreamingContext.
In this case pay attention to the lineage generated by your streaming.
Finally, check out [this](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/xml/parsers/StaxXmlParserUtils.scala), databricks resources are the best fit solution, sometimes

Comment: I understand but this specific use-case is about streaming. I do not understand last part of your answer.

Comment: when you define the ssc you have to set [batchDuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext) (the time interval at which streaming data will be divided into batches). Maybe the DStream generate RDD with cut lines because the batchDuration is not enough.
In the case you use streaming remember to use checkpointing because as bigger is batchDuration, more space is required in memory.
The last suggestion can I give is about the databrick's [library](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) to manage xml withspark.

Comment: Ok. I thought you were speaking about a higher order concept about batch duration management, not only batch duration setup. I understand. Good advice.